# SimpleDateFormat from l10n returns NullPointerException in iOS

Tags: codenameone

Code works fine in simulator and for Android. Returns a null pointer exception when built for ios and run on an iPad. This worked last year when my app was originally written.

```
   import java.util.Date;
   import com.codename1.l10n.SimpleDateFormat;

   public class StateMachine extends StateMachineBase {

    @Override
        protected void beforeNewSchedule(Form f) {            

            Date today = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());     
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");     
            String curDate = dateFormat.format(today);        
          }}
```

Console output

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at java_util_GregorianCalendar.computeFields:157
   at java_util_Calendar.complete:406
   at java_util_Calendar.setTimeInMillis:501
   at java_util_Calendar.__INIT__:345
   at java_util_GregorianCalendar.__INIT__:70
   at java_util_Calendar.getInstance:422
   at com_codename1_l10n_SimpleDateFormat.format:282
   at com_codename1_l10n_SimpleDateFormat.format:265
   at userclasses_StateMachine.beforeNewSchedule:51
   at generated_StateMachineBase.beforeShow:178
   at com_codename1_ui_util_UIBuilder_FormListener.run:2813
   at com_codename1_ui_Display.processSerialCalls:1152
   at com_codename1_ui_Display.edtLoopImpl:1096
   at com_codename1_ui_Display.mainEDTLoop:997
   at com_codename1_ui_RunnableWrapper.run:120
   at com_codename1_impl_CodenameOneThread.run:176
   at java_lang_Thread.runImpl:153
Nov 24 07:23:31 Barbaras-iPad MyApplication[1793] <Warning>:
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a regression related to [this commit](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/ebdc4df530878258142d8f000e3b2ced04cf8ccf) which fixed a timezone issue and effectively caused this cascading problem. It seems to only occur in specific timezones which is why we were unable to see this.

For now we deployed an older version of the VM to the servers to workaround this problem until we have a stabler fix.

Answer (score 0):

It works now !!! Thanks so much.

My time zone is Arizona where we don't ever change to Daylight savings time if that helps.